# SpringMVC get value from dynamic form input have the same name

Tags: spring-mvc, multiparameter

This is index.jsp page:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="channel">
        <option>Star Movie</option>
        <option>HBO</option>
        ...
        //More television channel option
    </select>
    <select name="channel">
        <option>Star Movie</option>
        <option>HBO</option>
        ...
        //More television channel option
    </select>
    ...
    //More select input added dynamic by user
    <button class="btn-add" >Add channel</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/channelReview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView actionChannelReview(@RequestParam("channel") String[] channelLst){
    ...
    //Do something else
}
```

The problem here is why channelLst is only have 1 element and it always the last value of  on the form, no matter how many  user add on form.

Answer (score 1):

I did not face any issue, i used the same code that you have mentioned, i got 2 channels in channelLst[image]

I also added dynamic dropdowns, working fine with any number of dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form method="post">
        <select name="channel">
            <option value="1">Star Movie</option>
            <option value="2">HBO</option>
            ...
            //More television channel option
        </select>
        <select name="channel">
            <option value="3">Star Movie</option>
            <option value="4">HBO</option>
            ...
            //More television channel option
        </select>
        ...
        //More select input added dynamic by user
        <button class="btn-add" >Add channel</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Now you will got the values ...... **vale** *attribute* wasn't given by you